# Magento 2.2.1 - Custom Theme cannot be applied to second site

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1

I've got a weird issue on my hands right now. I have created a custom theme, and I'm trying to apply it to one of my sites on Magento. There was not problem applying it to the first site(default), but when I tried to apply it to my second site it will not show up on the frontend.

In the backend it says that my custom theme is selected for all the sites, but the frontend is displaying the Luma theme. I have tried the following commands:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

None of these have helped, it seems to be 'stuck' on the luma theme. Any suggestions on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information for me, the both site is same place right? Are u using multi store and multi website?

Comment: @Daniel Black, Are you talking about multi-website concept ?. or both site are on different server ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was due to my homepage (a cms page) having a different theme applied then the rest of the site. Once I flipped the theme to my custom one it worked perfectly.